# show limited git diff status in ls, only in git directories

Tags: command-line, bash, git, bashrc

This might be an odd problem, but I would like to override the behavior of `ls` when in a git directory.

I want to extract some diff statistics from the last commit, and append it to the bottom of the `ls`. When in the **root** of the git project, I want to make a specific prompt like this:

```
app/
test/
.gitignore
test.py
run.py
README.md

+ 11 lines
- 3 lines
Last commit: "add a new test for deployment" (Oct 14, 2014)
```

When deeper than the root, I want to create a prompt like this (say I cd'd to `test/` and then use the `ls` command):

```
test/
├── __init__.py
├── test_deploy.py
└── test_add_user.py (+3 lines since last commit)
```

Bonus points: colorized green/red for plus/minus lines and nice uniform tabbing on git info.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to create a custom `ls`, the easiest way is to proceed as follows:

1. Create a directory `$HOME/bin`
2. Add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH`. To do this, open the file `~/.bashrc` in your favorite text editor, and add the following line to the end:

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Note that it is important that you *prepend* `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH`, so that executables in there will take precedence over other executables with the same name along your `PATH` (such as, in your case, the `ls` command)
3. Create a file `$HOME/bin/ls` with the contents that I'll post below.
4. Make it executable: `chmod 755 $HOME/bin/ls`.
5. You will probably need to restart your terminal.

Second, your new `$HOME/bin/ls` should behave like so: It checks if the current directory is a git repository, and

- if no, it simply delegates to the normal `/bin/ls` executable.
- if yes, it creates that output you asked for, depending on whether the current folder is the root of the git repository or if it is deeper.

I quickly hacked such a script together for you. It's by no means perfect, but it should be pretty close to what you want, and you can easily work your way from there. :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

# determine if we're in a git repo, what the root dir is, and assign it to GIT_ROOT, all in one swoop
GIT_ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)

# if not in git repo, relay to normal ls
if (( $? )); then
  /bin/ls "$@"

# if in git repo, are we in root dir?
elif [ "x$GIT_ROOT" = "x$PWD" ]; then
  # first, normal ls with 1 file per line, also pass along other parameters
  /bin/ls -1 "$@"
  echo
  # a few git stats
  GIT_DIFF=$(git diff --stat | tail -1)
  # any insertions?
  echo $GIT_DIFF | grep insertion >/dev/null
  if (( ! $? )); then
    # bonus points: color in green
    echo -e "\e[0;32m+ $(echo $GIT_DIFF | sed 's/.*, \([[:digit:]]\+\) insertion.*/\1/;') lines\e[0m"
  fi
  # any deletions?
  echo $GIT_DIFF | grep deletion >/dev/null
  if (( ! $? )); then
    # bonus points: color in red
    echo -e "\e[0;31m- $(echo $GIT_DIFF | sed 's/.*, \([[:digit:]]\+\) deletion.*/\1/;') lines\e[0m"
  fi
  # Finally, display last commit message and date
  git log -1 --pretty='Last commit: "%s" (%ad)'

# otherwise, we're depper in a git repo
else
  echo -e "\e[1;34m${PWD##*/}\e[0m"
  IFS=$'\n'
  for file in $(tree -C | tail -n +2 | head -n -2); do
    filename=$(echo $file | cut -d" " -f 2-)
    echo -n $file
    # a few git stats
    GIT_DIFF=$(git diff --stat "$(echo $filename | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")")
    # any insertions?
    echo $GIT_DIFF | grep insertion >/dev/null
    if (( ! $? )); then
      # bonus points: color in green
      echo -ne " \e[0;32m(+ $(echo $GIT_DIFF | sed 's/.*, \([[:digit:]]\+\) insertion.*/\1/;') lines since last commit)\e[0m"
    fi
    # any deletions?
    echo $GIT_DIFF | grep deletion >/dev/null
    if (( ! $? )); then
      # bonus points: color in red
      echo -ne " \e[0;31m(- $(echo $GIT_DIFF | sed 's/.*, \([[:digit:]]\+\) deletion.*/\1/;') lines since last commit)\e[0m"
    fi
    echo
  done

fi
```

## Demo

Note: output is nicely colored, though clearly this won't show here.

```
$ ls
app
README.md
run.py
test
test.py

+ 11 lines
- 3 lines
Last commit: "add a new test for deployment" (Fri Nov 21 04:20:37 2014 +0100)
$ cd test/
$ ls
test
├── bla
├── __init__.py
├── test_add_user.py (+ 3 lines since last commit)
└── test_deploy.py
```